# How to make Python 3 my default Python at command prompt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, command-prompt, enthought

I have uninstalled Python 2.7 and installed Python 3. But, when I type Python on my command prompt I get this :

"Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.9 ........."

How can I run Python 3 from command line or how can I make it default on my computer? I asked Enthought Canopy help and I was told that I can "have Canopy be your default Python only in a "Canopy Command Prompt". Not sure what it means.

edit : Thanks everyone. As suggested, I had to uninstall everything and install Python again.

Comment: What does `python3` give you? The easiest thing is probably to just create a `virtualenv` for the project with whatever interpreter you want, which also helps manage dependencies etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe's recommendation is spot-on. A brutal solution may be to change the python version the command `python` points to. Try. It's a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` (type `which python` just in case it's somewhere else)

Comment: Your system might rely on the fact that Python is Python2.7. You should simply create an alias.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I learned Python with 2.7, but I am starting a new course and Python 3 is required for the course.

Comment: I'm not sure how that relates to my suggestion, but OK!

Comment: For the record, you are using Windows. Not clear what/how you installed Python 3. Clearly you did not actually uninstall Canopy Python 2.7, since it is still running when you type "python" at the command line.

Comment: can you provide more details about the OS? Linux or Mac, Which linux distro etc.

Comment: I downloaded Python 3.4.3. The thing is I also still see Python 27 folder with Lib and Scripts files in it. I also have Python 34 folder now. I am using Windows 8.

Comment: Would you please remove all python related apps from your machine(including Python 3.4.3), and install Python 3.4.3 again and report the result.

Answer (score 0):

Windows selects which executable will be run by searching the directories in-order from the `PATH` environment variable ([source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120)):

> The shell now searches each directory specified by the PATH
>   environment variable, in the order listed, for an executable file
>   matching the command name. If a match is found, the external command
>   (the executable file) executes. If no match is found, the shell
>   reports an error and command processing completes.

You can [modify `PATH`](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to put your Python 3.4 directory (typically `C:\Python43`) before your Python 2.7 directory. From Windows 7 and up, you can use `where python` to confirm which `python` will be run (first line of the output).

Answer (score 0):

After editing each path and creating a new variable for each python version, be sure to rename the python.exe to a unique one. i.e. "python3x" . then you can call it in the command line as "python3x". I am assuming that the original python installed (2X) retains the python.exe of which when you call "python" in the command line, it will show the 2x version

Answer (score 0):

You can copy python.exe to python3.exe.

If you are using Anaconda, then you will find it in the sub directory of your environment, for intance, c:\Anaconda\envs\myenvironment.